# Develop app with multiple activities or one activity and multiple fragments?

Tags: java, android, navigation

Hi everyone as the title say I am wondering whats the best practice to design an android app should I make multiple activitites for each interface in my app or one activity that has multiple fragments(note:I am using a navigation buttombar)

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your need you can choose between activities and fragements. Activity is more like a complete separate page and fragment is a small view that can be called in an activity, multiple fragments can be used to display activities UI .
Fragments can be used to make dynamic views check this link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html. Hope this helps :)